# cypress test not working for drag and drop for dropping element in same area

Tags: html, reactjs, cypress

I am trying to test drag and drop using plugin [4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop](https://github.com/4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop). I have three elements, stacked one upon another. I need to pick first one and place under last element. So my drop zone is same from where I have picked the element. I trying to move element by using move and x- and y-position but it is not working and there are no errors. Can someone point-out what could be the potential issue?

In the below html div with id `drag-index-0`, `drag-index-1`, `drag-index-2` are the only draggable areas.

HTML:

```
<div id="options-selected">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="drag-index-0">
                <span>star</span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 140px;">
                <input value="First element" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 47px;">
                <button type="button">
                    <span>add</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button">
                    <span>delete</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="drag-index-1">
                <span>star</span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 140px;">
                <input value="Second element" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 47px;">
                <button type="button">
                    <span>add</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button">
                    <span>delete</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="drag-index-2">
                <span>star</span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 140px;">
                <input value="Third element" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 47px;">
                <button type="button">
                    <span>add</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button">
                    <span>delete</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cypress test:

```
cy.get('#drag-index-0')
      .move({ deltaX: 80, deltaY: -100, force: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below plugin-free solution:

```
cy.get("#drag-index-0")
.trigger('mousedown', { //simulating hold click
    button: 0
}).wait(750)
.trigger('mousemove', { //simulating drag
    pageX: 80, 
    pageY: -100,
    force: true
}).wait(250)
.trigger('mouseup', {  //simulating drop
    force: true
});
```